# ASP.NET codebehind changes do not show up

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, code-behind

I am trying to make changes to the C# codebehind for an asp.net file. After compiling and publishing it in Visual Studio, none of the changes in aspx.cs appear, while changes to the aspx file do. I have also deleted the contents of the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder to no effect.

Is there something I am missing that prevents the changes from showing up?

Comment: Check Project > Properties > Package/Product Web > Items to deploy. Is it set to all files in the project folder?

Comment: what do you mean 'none of the changes in aspx.cs appear'? Where you're looking at changes? On published site?

Comment: @EFeit It was not, however I have made the change and the issue still persists.

Comment: @Alex I apologize for the confusion. Simple changes to the code, such as different web pages for redirects, are not reflected on the published site. However, any changes to the aspx file are.

Comment: did you try to clean browser cache?

Comment: Are you deploying this to a server or localhost?

Comment: Is this a WebApp? Try building it. Ctrl+Shift+B in VS

Comment: @Alex Yes, I did try clearing the browser cache, but there was no change.

Comment: @EFeit It is being deployed to a localhost.

Comment: @JackPettinger This is a WebApp, and that was the method I was using to build.

Comment: if you debug it just pressing F5 in VS?

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately I am not able to debug in VS because the site is hosted on a different computer than what I am able to develop on. I am also not able to use the VS Remote Debugger due to the accounts being on different domains. Right now I am just copying and pasting files haha. Could that be part of the issue? I am making sure to do a direct copy with all of the dlls.

Comment: I'm starting to think the changes in the code behind aren't doing what you think they should. Did you try a simple `Response.Write("something")`, then build, then debug, and see if it shows up?

Comment: what do you mean just copying? Did you built and published site? And anyway you should be able to run it locally using development web server, embedded in VS.

Comment: Agreed with @Alex. Go back into Project Settings > Web. Under servers select "Use Visual Studio Development Server" and "Auto-assign Port." Build and debug your solution locally. I thought this is what you were doing the entire time, sorry!

Comment: okay, probably I guess what is your problem. You just changed .aspx and .cs files and copied them to server. You need to build web site and then .dlls in bin folder will be changed. And you need to replace them on the server.

Comment: @EFiet Alex Haha, no worries! Those Web settings were the same as I had, and when I had tried debugging before, I received an error about a reference that could not be resolved, and the reference being a file on a different domain. That's why I was hoping just copying and pasting would work haha. Also, the method I used to build the website was first Build Solution, and then Publish Website. And I notice that the dll are changed. Is there another way to build the website?

Comment: Alright, now it works. And I have no idea why haha. I did another Clean Solution, Build Solution, and then Publish Website, all things I had done before, but copying it over this time fixed it. I'm chalking it up to Magic. Thanks @Alex for all your help with which was admittedly a pretty vague situation.

Comment: And thanks @EFeit! I appreciate your help through this.

Comment: Ok, turns out it wasn't Magic. Before running Clean Solution, I had deleted the dll assembled by Visual Studio in my bin folder. And, it turns out when I run Clean Solution, it does not delete the dll it assembles, which I was assuming it had. I'm pretty sure now doing a hard removal of the dll is what fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What ended up fixing the issue was deleting the dll assembled by Visual Studio from the project bin folder. I had assumed Visual Studio removed it when running Clean Solution, but it appears it does not. I verified the name of the assembled dll by going to Project Properties > Application and then checking the Assembly name.

After deleting the assembled dll, I ran Clean Solution, Build Solution, and Publish Project, and then everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues a couple of times. Try the following solution:

1. Close Visual Studio 2012.
2. Clear the c:\Users[your_user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas\ folder.
3. Reopen your application.